# Why is the ComboBoxColumn very slow on drop-down open in DataGrid WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, datagrid, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I am using C# WPF and currently, I am loading some data from the database in Datagrid.

I loading more than 24,000 rows from a table in the database into `DataGridComboBoxColumn`, the problem is that when I open the Combobox it is very slow so it takes about  30 seconds to display the records

I solved that problem in `DataGridTemplateColumn` here is the XAML :

```xml
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="ComboBox Element" Width="120">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ComboBox x:Name="ComboBox_Commodity"
                                          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TheCommodityCombo_DATA, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
                                          SelectedValue="{Binding CommodityID}"
                                          DisplayMemberPath="CommodityName"
                                          SelectedValuePath="CommodityCode"
                                          
                                          IsTextSearchEnabled="True"
                                          IsEditable="True"
                                          SelectedIndex="0"  BorderBrush="#FFADEEB4" Background="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="1" PreviewLostKeyboardFocus="ComboBox_Commodity_PreviewLostKeyboardFocus">
                                    <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
                                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                            <VirtualizingStackPanel VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"/>
                                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
                                </ComboBox>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

but I don't want use `DataGridTemplateColumn` because in the combobox element  doen't firing the CellEndEdit event

so **I'm using `DataGridComboBoxColumn`**

**XAML**:

```xml
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn Width="160" Header="DataGridComboBoxColumn"
                                            SelectedValueBinding="{Binding CommodityID}" 
                                            DisplayMemberPath="CommodityName" 
                                            SelectedValuePath="CommodityCode">
                        <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                                <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=TheCommodityCombo_DATA, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" />
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                        
                        <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                                <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=TheCommodityCombo_DATA, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" />
                                <Setter Property="SelectedIndex" Value="0"/>
                                <Setter Property="IsEditable" Value="True"/>
                                
                                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="True"/>
                                <Setter Property="VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing" Value="True"/>
                                <Setter Property="VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode" Value="Recycling"/>
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                    </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

**My issue is** : the settings that I made exactly like the `ComboBox` in `DataGridTemplateColumn` do not work for the `DataGridComboBoxColumn`! and DataGridComboBoxColumn on opening combobox is so much slow

How do I fix this ↑ ?

similar problem but in Templatecolumn : [Combox column in wpf datagrid performance issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14143416/combox-column-in-wpf-datagrid-performance-issue)

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14143416/combox-column-in-wpf-datagrid-performance-issue

Comment: _I loading more than 24,000 rows from a table in the database into DataGridComboBoxColumn,_ perhaps this is your real problem. What do you think will do your user with a combo containing 24000 items?. Do you expect them to choose an element from that list?

Comment: it's not my answer , I need solve it in DataGridComboBoxColumn         ,   Not TemplateColumn combobox element

Comment: May I give you an advice? This is a terrible UI solution for your users. Instead provide a button and if and only if a user wants to change the item they will press the button, you will show a separate form with a textbox to start a search of your database providing only the items that match the typed text.

Comment: dear Steve , thanks for your advice , but in loading everything is good and Items source of my DataGridComboBoxColumn It is filled once , So far, it's like the DataGridTemplateColumn  , but my problem is that the settings that are used to increase the speed of the template are not applied to the DataGridComboBoxColumn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unable to test the solution below and it does not fit in a comment but it seems like you are trying to style VirtualizingStackPanel without first creating one for a ComboBox.

First define your ItemsPanelTemplate:

```
<Window.Resources>
  <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="VSP">
     <VirtualizingStackPanel IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizationMode="Recycling"/>
  </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

Then style your DataGridComboBoxColumn's ComboBox to use this ItemsPanelTemplate.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
  <Setter Property="ItemsPanel" Value="{StaticResource VSP}" />
```

This should replace ItemsPanel with your configured VirtualizingItemsPanel.

Source: http://vbcity.com/blogs/xtab/archive/2009/12/15/wpf-using-a-virtualizingstackpanel-to-improve-combobox-performance.aspx

Answer (score 1):

ComboBox element can fire the CellEndEdit event

ComboBox should be contained in **CellEditingTemplate** instead of **CellTemplate**

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ItemList}" x:Name="dataGrid" CellEditEnding="dataGrid_CellEditEnding">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="ComboBox Element" Width="120">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ItemList}"
                                                IsEditable="True">
                    </ComboBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

ComboBox is created(Initialized) when entering edit mode..

It will help improve performance